# Invalid syntax with if statement

Tags: python, syntax, if-statement, python-3.x

I will just paste in the entire function, as it is not that long:

```
def decideTile():
    global tile
    global exp
    global maxexp

    tile += 1
    exp += math.ceil(random.randrange(math.ceil((maxexp/2)/2,maxexp/2))

    if exp >= maxexp:
       levelUp()
    else:
       tileChoices = ['Battle','Loot','Nothing']
       fileType = random.choice(tileChoices)

    if tileType == 'Battle':
        battle()
    elif tileType == 'Loot':
        loot()
    elif tileType == 'Nothing':
        nothing()
```

Now, Python is saying that the

```
if exp >= maxexp:
```

part of it is 'invalid syntax', and I'm not entirely sure why. Help is appreciated!

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that works best for you (click on the green check mark by it).  For more complicated questions/answers you might want to wait a few hours and then pick the most complete (which may not be the first ;).

Answer (score 10):

There's a parenthesis missing in the previous line. To fix the problem just add a closing parenthesis to the end of that line as follows:

```
exp += math.ceil(random.randrange(math.ceil((maxexp/2)/2,maxexp/2)))
```

Comment: The program I use underlines the corresponding parentheses, and all of them seemed to be closed... weird. Embarassing solution, but thank you nonetheless.

Comment: jcollado is correct. I recommend using Pyflakes to avoid common pitfalls in Python code.

Comment: Yes, I second [pyflakes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) recommendation. Also, note that it can be integrated with many text editors to check your syntax as you write.

Answer (score 0):

Unclosed brackets caused the error. The line should be:

```
exp += math.ceil(random.randrange(math.ceil((maxexp/2)/2,maxexp/2)))
```